# How to arrange and rename files according to number?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, file, file-rename

I want to arrange files first and rename them according to their order that is specified by a number in the file name.

**For example:**

I have a folder that contains a bunch of different files. The file names are indicated by a number at the end of it. Let's say we have the following files in that folder:

```
file_1.xml  // Remains unchanged
file_2.xml  // Remains unchanged
file_4.xml  // Should be renamed to "file_3.xml"
file_9.xml  // Should be renamed to "file_4.xml"
file_12.xml // Should be renamed to "file_5.xml"
```

How do I do that? I want to create a reliable clean method that renames files in order.

**So far:**

```
private void updateFilesName() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= filesAmount; i++) {
        File file1 = new File(getFilesDir().getParent() + "/file_" + i + ".xml");
        File file2 = new File(getFilesDir().getParent() + "/file_" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".xml");
        if (!file1.exists() && file2.exists()) {
            file2.renameTo(file1);
        }
    }
}
```

But that only works if the difference between 2 file positions was 1. (like between `file_2` and `file_4`) This method won't work for `file_9` and `file_12`.

Comment: Put them into a List, sort them. Rename them in order of the list.

Comment: It looks as if OP sorted the list already. Please tell.

Comment: Is it important in your example that say file_2.xml keeps that name? Or are you satisfied that after the operation you have file names with _1 to _5 ? And for instance _5 was _2 before?

Comment: Yes, file_1.xml and file_2.xml must remain unchanged. I edited my question to clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void updateFilesName() {
    int j;
    for (int i = 1; i <= filesAmount; i++) {
        File file1 = new File(getFilesDir().getParent() + "/file_" + i + ".xml");
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            j = i+1;     
            while (!(new File(getFilesDir().getParent() + "/file_" + j + ".xml")).exists()) {
                j++; 
            }
            (new File(getFilesDir().getParent() + "/file_" + j + ".xml")).renameTo(file1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Iterate all files under the directory and check the file name
    File folder = new File("urdirectory");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        if (!listOfFiles[i].getName().equals("file_" + (i+1) + ".xml")) {
            File tempFile1 = listOfFiles[i];
            File tempFile2 = new File("urdirectory" + "/file_" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".xml");
            tempFile.renameTo(tempFile2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work if there are for instance two files and their sequence is file_2.xml, file_1.xml.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that didn't arrange my files correctly.

Comment: I don't know exactly. It's hard to decipher, but I think the reason is how `listFiles()` method arranges the files. It doesn't arrange the files in the array according to file numbers.